# how do you view subscriptions in discord desktop program?

Tags: discord

how do you view subscriptions in discord?

I subscribed a few months ago to a discord server.. I only have the one subscription

but I want to view all subscriptions so that that subscription shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

- In the Discord desktop program, click the Settings gear icon at the bottom-left
- Switch to the Subscriptions tab on the left
- You will see the list under “Your Subscriptions”.